# how is this sizeof expression evaluated? and why it is called that way?

Tags: c++

I came across with this code in an `std::optional` implementation :

```
template <class T, class U>
struct is_assignable
{
  template <class X, class Y>
  constexpr static bool has_assign(...) { return false; }

  template <class X, class Y, size_t S = sizeof((std::declval<X>() = std::declval<Y>(), true)) >
  // the comma operator is necessary for the cases where operator= returns void
  constexpr static bool has_assign(bool) { return true; }

  constexpr static bool value = has_assign<T, U>(true);
};
```

The part that I cant understand how it works or how it is evaluated is `size_t S = sizeof((std::declval<X>() = std::declval<Y>(), true))` I know that if the assign operation fails it will fall back to the first definition of has_assign that returns false, but i don't know why it has the `, true)` part.

I did some test with structs that returns void on the assign operator and removing the `, true` part in `sizeof` gives me the same results.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae . If the expression inside `sizeof` is valid for given `X` and `Y`, then there are two overloads of `has_assign`, and the second one is chosen for `has_assign<T, U>(true)` as a better match. If the expression is meaningless, then that overload is discarded, and the first one is chosen.

Comment: Some compilers define `sizeof(void) == 1` as an extension. Enable more warnings.

Comment: Would be more direct to just write `class S = decltype(std::declval<X>() = std::declval<Y>())`. We don't care what `S` is anyway, just that that expression is valid.

Comment: @SamVashavchik The way I understand this question, it's *not* about SFINAE. The OP even says "I know that if the assign operation fails it will fall back to the first definition of has_assign that returns false..." The real question is why the comma operator (`, true`) is used, which has little to do with SFINAE itself.

Comment: @Quentin The code in question does not pass an expression of type `void` to `sizeof`. The relevance of your comment to the issue at hand is unclear to me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: it absolutely does if `X::operator=(Y&&)` returns `void`.

Comment: @Fanael Does not. Look closer at what's inside `sizeof`. It's `sizeof(something=something, true)`. I suppose it could be made to break if I make `X::operator=(Y)` return a class that overloads `operator,()`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm commenting on OP's last sentence, where "[...] removing the `, true` part in `sizeof` gives [her] the same results".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: read the question again, especially this part: "I did some test with structs that returns void on the assign operator and removing the `, true` part in `sizeof` gives me the same results."

Comment: @Fanael I see. I have misunderstood the thrust of the question. Never mind me, then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to apply `sizeof()`, you need a complete type. But returning a complete type isn't a requirement of assignability, hence:

```
sizeof((std::declval<X>() = std::declval<Y>(), true))
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ expr ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

if the assignment is valid for those two types, then we have `sizeof(expr)` where the type of `expr` is `bool` (because `true`). So if the assignment is valid, we get some real `size`. Otherwise, substitution failure.

---

But this is an unnecessarily cryptic way of writing this code. Moreover, it's not even correct because I could write a type like:

```
struct Evil {
    template <class T> Evil operator=(T&& ); // assignable from anything
    void operator,(bool);                    // mwahahaha
};
```

and now your `sizeof()` still doesn't work.

Instead, prefer simply:

```
class = decltype(std::declval<X>() = std::declval<Y>())
```

This accomplishes the same result - either substitution failure or not - without needed to care at all about what the type of the result is or to handle special cases.

Comment: Would the original code works on some compilers (maybe older and not fully complaint with the standard)?

One possible advantage might be in generated code. Since `sizeof(true)` would always give the same size (assuming all files compiled with compatible options), then it would help ensure that only one function is kept if inlining is not done...

Comment: @Phil1970 This is all done at compile time. None of these functions should appear in the object file.

Comment: Just a note, there are some cases where is_assignable (even the standard one) can give you a false positive. But I think  a new question could be posted on the matter. [gist](https://gist.github.com/aindigo/69bf0ca558a127321af70dbb82314f5c)

Comment: @alter That's because `Ex1::operator=` is lying about what types it's assignable from. That's not a `std::is_assignable` problem.

Answer (score 8):

In principle, the type of the expression `std::declval<X>() = std::declval<Y>()` (that is, the return type of the `operator =` involved) can be arbitrary, including an incomplete type or `void`. In such case, SFINAE wouldn't kick in, since the expression is valid. However, you'd then get an error from applying `sizeof` to an incomplete type. (Note that some compilers define `sizeof(void) == 1` as an extension, but that cannot be universally relied upon).

Adding `, true` after the SFINAE expression fixes this by discarding the type of the assignment (whatever it is), and applying `sizeof` to `true` instead (which is perfectly valid).

As indicated by [Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry) in the comments, a more direct approach would be to use the type of the assignment in `decltype` instead of in `sizeof`, like this:

```
template <class X, class Y, class S = decltype(std::declval<X>() = std::declval<Y>()) >
constexpr static bool has_assign(bool) { return true; }
```